# What is the runtime and recurrence relation of the check BST function?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, runtime, binary-search-tree, recurrence

How do I get the base case and the overall runtime of this code snippet:

```
maxN -> gets the maximum value at the subtree = O(log n) 

minN -> gets the minimum value at the subtree = O(log n) 

bool check_bst(NODE *t) { 
   if(t==NULL) return true; 
   if(!check_bst(t->left) || !check_bst(t->right)) 
      return false;
   if(t->left != NULL && maxN(t->left) >= t->val) 
      return false; 
   if(t->right != NULL && minN(t->right) <= t->val) 
      return false; 
   return true; 
}
```

Is it `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n`? `O(nlogn)`?

Comment: Unclear. Could you elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

If run time of maxN and minN is O(lgn), then the run time of `check_bst` should be

> T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(lgn)

T(n) is O(n).
You can refer to [enter link description here](http://qa.geeksforgeeks.org/160/qa.geeksforgeeks.org/160/what-is-solution-of-t-n-2t-n-2-logn)